# Seaborn lineplot unexpected behaviour in the range of xticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, line-plot, xticks

I am starting my studies on pandas and seaborn. I'm testing the lineplot, but the plot's x-axis does not show the range I expected for this attribute (`num_of_elements`). I expected that each value of this attribute shows up on the x-axis. Can someone explain what I'm missing on this plot? Thanks.

This is the code I'm using:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import ticker

df_scability = pd.DataFrame()

df_scability['num_of_elements'] = [13,28,43,58,73,88,93,108,123,138]
df_scability['time_minutes'] = [2,3,5,7,20,30,40,50,60,90]
df_scability['dataset'] = ['Top 10 users','Top 10 users','Top 10 users','Top 10 users','Top 10 users','Top 10 users',
                           'Top 10 users','Top 10 users','Top 10 users','Top 10 users']

dpi = 600
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3, 2),dpi=dpi)
ax = sns.lineplot(x = "num_of_elements", y = "time_minutes", hue='dataset', err_style='bars', data = df_scability)

ax.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize=4)
sns.despine(offset=0, trim=True, left=True)
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(10))
ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_ymajorticklabels(), fontsize = 6)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter())
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xmajorticklabels(), fontsize = 6)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter())
plt.ylabel('AVG time (min)',fontsize=7)
plt.xlabel('Number of elements',fontsize=7)
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

This code generates it as output for me:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
sns.despine(offset=0, trim=True, left=True)
```

removes the spines from plot, so it could cause confusion. The x axis is actually going from 6.75 to 144.25:

```
print(ax.get_xlim())
# (6.75, 144.25)
```

But only ticks for 50 and 100 values are shown.
So you can fix x axis range with:

```
ax.set_xticks(range(0, 150 + 50, 50))
```

before call the `despine`. `0` is the lowest tick, `150` the highest and `50` the step among ticks. You can tailor them on your needs.

### Complete Code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import ticker

df_scability = pd.DataFrame()

df_scability['num_of_elements'] = [13,28,43,58,73,88,93,108,123,138]
df_scability['time_minutes'] = [2,3,5,7,20,30,40,50,60,90]
df_scability['dataset'] = ['Top 10 users','Top 10 users','Top 10 users','Top 10 users','Top 10 users','Top 10 users',
                           'Top 10 users','Top 10 users','Top 10 users','Top 10 users']

dpi = 600
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3, 2),dpi=dpi)
ax = sns.lineplot(x = "num_of_elements", y = "time_minutes", hue='dataset', err_style='bars', data = df_scability)

ax.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize=4)
ax.set_xticks(range(0, 150 + 50, 50))
sns.despine(offset=0, trim=True, left=True)
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(10))
ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_ymajorticklabels(), fontsize = 6)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter())
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xmajorticklabels(), fontsize = 6)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter())
plt.ylabel('AVG time (min)',fontsize=7)
plt.xlabel('Number of elements',fontsize=7)
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Tkx @Zephyr. It worked for me. However, I have a question about the ticks. You said that the _despine_ removes the spines from the plot and only the ticks 50 and 100 values are shown. I would like to show exactly each value on the x-axis. For that, I just replaced the _range_ with the list values in 'num_of_elements'.

Comment: Yes, you can pass to `ax.set_xticks` the list of ticks you want to display